# Four black wires and four white

Tags: electrical

Changing my light switches and had to change the metal outlet box due to the old one just being awful, I derped and forgot to take a picture of the old setup, I remember the white wires being pigtailed together and I think the black wires as well but now I cannot remember....

Help! [image]

Comment: Whites should only be on switches with a single cable(one switch, one cable), a switch loop(old style).  What did the switches control before?  Four cables can mean quite a few setups.  Two power to two light sets are the best/easiest option we might figure out.  Are the switches the same as the old ones?  If the old ones were three way, you are ...

Comment: The switches are similar but not exactly the same (new switches have a green screw on them) the switches controlled a light next to the bathroom and a light in the living area. (two switches total)

Comment: Hopefully you have two power/hot/live cables and two light control cables.  Separate all the wires and with the breakers on carefully test which black wires read 120v to ground(box)  You should need two breakers on, one for each power cable.

Comment: Looks like only one wire is hot, not sure if it's because one light fixture has burnt out bulbs or not.

Comment: You might need to get an electrician in.  The light bulbs/fixtures should not matter.  You have an unknown wire with no propose right now.  It either comes from panel/power or goes to an unknown(to you) light/outlet.  Too many unknowns to fix over the internet.  We do not know the wiring of your house, so fire/shocks is a greater chance you take if we are wrong.

Comment: So it looks as though the half bath light is also on the same circuit. Perhaps you're right I should call an electrician but I'm sure this can be solved without spending the $200 for a house call

Comment: Quite possible, but you will need the time to trace unknown circuits.  If you have the time, the tools needed do not cost that much(almost).

Comment: I have lots of time, well approx 4 days haha.

Comment: Looks to me like the two black wires at the top were nutted together, like the two white wires.  (At least, based on the amount of twist in the wires.)

Answer (score 1):

You will need a [non contact tester](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B099SJ6469) a few wire nuts and 3 different colors of tape.

With the breaker off disconnect all wires white and black. ( grounds can stay connected in the box.)  Cap all wires with a wire nut and separate them so they are not touching each other or the box.

Turn the breaker on and carefully test (with the tester.) what wire/s have power. The ones with power mark with a piece of tape.

If none of the white wires have power connect all of them together. Use an appropriate wire nut.

If you get this far and your findings are 1 black with power and no white wires with power you have no switch loop and it's a good scenario.  If not you may be better off calling an electrician.

Now turn off the breaker and connect the one wire with power to any one other black wire.  See what gets power transferred to. ( light next to the bath, living area light, 1/2 bath)  Use a different color to mark that black wire.

Repeat the same test with the 2 remaining black wires.  That will tell you what those wires service.  Mark them accordingly. Turn the breaker off when connecting the wires, back on just for the test.

Now if you have black wire marked as :
One with power from the breaker box
One carrying power to the light next to the bath
One carrying power to the living area light
One carrying power to the 1/2 bath.

```
                    Breaker off
```

You can now connect the wire that carries power to the living area light to one of the screws on a new switch.

Connect the wire for the light next to the bath to one screw on another new switch.

Connect the black wire carrying power from the breaker box to the wire to the 1/2 bath light and add 2 pigtails of about 7 inches (black wire of the same gauge.)  This gives you 4 black wires connecter together. The 2 pigtails go to the remaining screws of the switches. ( one on each screw) .

Now you have power from the breaker box going to the 1/2 bath and providing power to the 2 switches.  All neutrals (white) tied together.  grounds tied in the box.

Turn on the breaker.  the switches should work the 2 lights. There should be power to the 1/2 bath light.  You have no wires unaccounted for.

Answer (score 1):

It's almost guaranteed the single hot wire is a home run to your breaker box, two of the cables are to the lights, and the other wire is to the next receptacle in the circuit.

Easiest way to figure it out is connect the hot to a switch on the line screw, connect 1 of the other black wires to the load screw, turn on breaker and flip switch, see which light turned on (if no light turned on then you found which wire is running to the next receptacle)

Mark your light cables - wire nut or wago the hot+next receptacle wires and 2 pigtails, one for each switch line.  The whites are all together with one wire nut.

Easy peasy